# Limit characters being added to an element in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm trying to create a web app based on the TV show countdown in which the user picks 8 letters either vowel or consonant. I was able to create buttons which generate either one but I don't know how to limit the letter container to only 8 characters.

I'm completely stuck on what to do next. I don't know if i need to create an array or if there is away to set a limit to the letterContainer element. Please see my code below:

```
var counter = 0;

while(counter<=8){
counter++;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", genCon);
}

function genCon() {

  var letterContainer = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0];

  var con = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * con.length));

  var randomCon = con[randomNumber];

  var addCon = document.createTextNode(randomCon.toUpperCase());

  letterContainer.appendChild(addCon);

}

document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", genVowel);

var letterContainer = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0];

function genVowel() {

  var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * vowel.length));

  var randomVowel = vowel[randomNumber];

  var addVowel = document.createTextNode(randomVowel.toUpperCase());

  letterContainer.appendChild(addVowel);

}
```

Comment: You could add a counter on each event so when you press your buttons it would increment the counter. When the counter is 8, don't pick a random letter.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong but this is what I tried and no luck :(

Comment: I think you're on the right track... instead of appending it to the element and trying to control it's length - try appending the values to a javascript variable. This setter could decide if it should add one more letter, or if it should ignore the event.

Comment: `while(counter<=8)` will still execute if counter is 8

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers :) this has helped but I don't know how I would have figured it out on my own :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be pretty simple if you use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com). The `rando()` function will pick a character from a string for you. And to limit the number of characters to 8, just check that it's currently less than 8 before adding.

```js
function pickFrom(letters) {
  var board = document.getElementById("board");
  if (board.innerHTML.length < 8) board.innerHTML += rando(letters);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<h2 id="board"></h2>
<button onclick="pickFrom('BCDFGHJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ');">Consonant</button>
<button onclick="pickFrom('AEIOU');">Vowel</button>
```

Note that, because this uses randojs, you must have this in the head of your html document for this code to work:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer Aaron, you made it seem so simple! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments in the snippet below to explain a way of controlling the max allowed length of the result.

If you don't want the letters to stop at eight, but you'll want to push the earlier character out, you can replace `addLetter` with

```
function addLetter(letter) {
  text = (text + letter).slice(-8);
}
```

```js
const consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "z"]; // omitted some
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

const letterContainer = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0];
document.querySelector("#addConsonant").addEventListener("click", genCon);
document.querySelector("#addVowel").addEventListener("click", genVowel);

// You could keep the results in this variable
let text = '';

// Calling this function to update it with the letter of your choice
function addLetter(letter) {
  // but it will also control the length of it
  if (text.length <= 8)
    text += letter;
}

function pickRandomFrom(collection) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * collection.length));

  return collection[randomNumber];
}

// then write the results to HTML
function genCon() {
  addLetter(pickRandomFrom(consonants));
  letterContainer.innerText = text.toUpperCase();
}

function genVowel() {
  addLetter(pickRandomFrom(vowels));
  letterContainer.innerText = text.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<h2>

</h2>
<button id="addConsonant">
Add Consonant
</button>
<button id="addVowel">
Add Vowel
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Was trying to get my head around your code as I'm not used to using const and let, I don't know how I would have figured this out on my own. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @cpog90 oh sorry about that, totally forgot I used them instead of `var` - if you haven't already looked up I think it's fair to summarize them as `let` behaves exactly like `var` (in other words, you can reassign any value to it) while `const` only lets you specify the value once (but keep in mind for things like objects you can still _mutate_ them, even if they're in a `const` variable). I'm happy if I could help you with the above, have fun coding!

Comment: Thanks Alex, no need to be sorry it's best I get used to seeing the different types of variables. That's really good info to know :) Really appreciate it my friend!